# how to access wpfusercontrol methods from a class

Tags: wpf, user-controls

In a WPF User control Library project, I created a class “my class”.
While constructing this class, from the user control I passed the object of usercontrol.
Now I need to call the user control methods into the class “my class”.

Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the object of the usercontrol, you can access the methods inside using that.

```
UserControlObject.MethodName();
```